# Don't include margin/padding in width when nesting divs

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have an overlay over a clip thumbnail, and a click event to open the iFrame. The overlay will contain the JSON response data about the clip, however, I'm having trouble styling the overlay to not include the margins in the overlay's total size. This, for obvious reasons, makes aligning text very problematic.

So how would I make it so the overlay takes that same margin, without adding the margin to the overlay effectively doubling the margin entirely?

```css
#clips {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.clipImg {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.clipImg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 496;
  height: 272;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clipImg-container:hover .clipImg-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipImg-container" data-slug="ManlyEnjoyableSowKappaPride"><img src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/28966899744-offset-8838-preview-480x272.jpg" class="clipImg">
  <div class="clipImg-overlay"><img id="channel-logo" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d7747302-0948-478a-9017-976d285a2678-profile_image-150x150.png">
    <div id="info-container">
      <h1 id="clip-name">CODE BLUE CODE BLUE | Tip for free !loots</h1>
      <p id="clip-context">CodeSpent is playing PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS</p>
      <p id="clip-views">4 views</p>
      <p id="clip-curation">Clipped by sudocodesh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.clipImg-overlay` is relative to the `.clipImg-container`, that expands with the `.clipImg` margin.

To resolve this you could try to use the margin in the `.clipImg-container` or make a div that surrounds `.clipImg-overlay` and `.clipImg` and have the margin that is actually in `.clipImg`.

```
<style>
  .clipImg {
    flex: 1;
  }

  .clipImg-container {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
</style>
<div class="clipImg-container" data-slug="ManlyEnjoyableSowKappaPride">
  <img src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/28966899744-offset-8838-preview-480x272.jpg" class="clipImg">
  <div class="clipImg-overlay">
    <img id="channel-logo" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d7747302-0948-478a-9017-976d285a2678-profile_image-150x150.png">
    <div id="info-container">
      <h1 id="clip-name">CODE BLUE CODE BLUE | Tip for free !loots</h1>
      <p id="clip-context">CodeSpent is playing PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS</p>
      <p id="clip-views">4 views</p>
      <p id="clip-curation">Clipped by sudocodesh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<style>
  .overlay-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
</style>
<div class="clipImg-container" data-slug="ManlyEnjoyableSowKappaPride">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <img src="https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/28966899744-offset-8838-preview-480x272.jpg" class="clipImg">
    <div class="clipImg-overlay">
      <img id="channel-logo" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/d7747302-0948-478a-9017-976d285a2678-profile_image-150x150.png">
      <div id="info-container">
        <h1 id="clip-name">CODE BLUE CODE BLUE | Tip for free !loots</h1>
        <p id="clip-context">CodeSpent is playing PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS</p>
        <p id="clip-views">4 views</p>
        <p id="clip-curation">Clipped by sudocodesh</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I actually did realize soon after that there was some clutter and lack of attention to how the margins were nested themselves and not treated properly. Gave the overlay a padding to match the margin and that worked perfectly.